# What is the purpose of the octal digit 0 permission

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am more familiar with `drwx` permissions, but I would like to learn about the octal permission does `0` represent `-` ? I understand that `r` represents `4` w represents `2` and x represents `1`. I don't properly understand what 0 stands for.

*For example*

the symbolic representation of

0774

would be

rwxrwxr

but I don't understand the purpose of the 0.

Comment: Do you mean what does `8` represent? As in the 0 in chmod 0755 xyz?

Comment: no that's not what  I mean @JoshuaRahm I added an example to the question. Maybe you can understand it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linux permissions there are *four* octal digits for permissions. There are the 3 everyone knows about, read, write and execute, but there are an extra 3 bits in the permissions:

- The sticky bit
- The set gid bit
- The set uid bit

So setting the permissions 4755 sets the setuid bit, as well as `rwxrw-rw-'

likewise 2755 sets the setgid bit and 1755 sets the sticky bit. Any combination of these can be set:

- 1 sticky bit
- 2 setgid bit
- 3 setgid bit & sticky bit
- 4 setuid bit
- 5 setuid bit & sticky bit
- 6 setuid bit & setgid bit
- 7 setuid bit & setgid bit & sticky bit

These bits mean something different for files vs directories.

On files, the

- sticky bit does nothing (it used to tell the kernel to retain that file in  cache)
- setuid bit if the file is an executable, when executed, it will run as the *owner of the file*, not as the one who ran it (this is how `sudo` works to give you root privileges -- it runs as `root` even if it was invoked by a user like `guest`)
- setgid bit like the setuid bit except for the group owner.

On folders, the

- sticky bit on a 777 folder will allow users to remove their own files, but will *not* allow users to remove *other* users files. Without the sticky bit set any user could remove any other user's files under this directory. (this is how `/tmp` works)
- setuid bit on a folder does nothing so far as I'm aware
- setgid bit on a folder will enforce that all new files created in that directory will inherit the group of that folder instead of the default group of the user who created then.

Although these permissions are important and UNIX wouldn't work without them, in general it is good to avoid their use (at least for files) because a poorly written program could end up giving free root to anyone who runs it. So it is better to leave it to sudo to be the gatekeeper of root.

Comment: Thank you for the info !

Answer (score 5):

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html

```
   S_ISUID     04000   set-user-ID bit
   S_ISGID     02000   set-group-ID bit (see below)
   S_ISVTX     01000   sticky bit (see below)
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

In Unix conventions, written numbers are assumed to be decimal unless they are prefixed with a `0x` (or `0X`) in which case they are hexadecimal or prefixed with `0` which indicates they are octal numbers.

The `chmod` command (probably?) isn't performing general number parsing (simple string parsing will do), but programmers who write the examples and documentation would prefix an octal number with `0` just to be sure and clear.

Comment: While it is true in a lot of contexts (e.g. in C source codes) that integer numbers with a leading 0 are octal numbers, this is not true for `chmod`. This command accepts both symbolic and numeric mode specifiers and assumes that any number is octal.

Comment: Upvoted: "... would prefix an octal number with `0` just [to] be sure and clear". While the top two answers above are completely correct, I think this is actually the best answer as to why the seemingly superfluous `0` digit is given in the example.